# write.table can't display row names. Updated with a replicate

Tags: r

I've tried to take out my data [with the row names as dates displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2IZG.png)

[image]

```
write.table(name, file = "names.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)
```

But all I got was consecutive numbers not dates as displayed. I toggled `quote = on` and `off` and nothing seems to work.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for the comments and I am so very sorry I did not attach the codes earlier because I thought it was because I used the wrong code. Here is a replicate,

```
volEnv <- new.env()

require(quantmod)

MonthlyAd <- function(x){
sym <- sub("\\..*$", "", names(x)[1])
Ad(to.monthly(x, indexAt = 'lastof', drop.time = TRUE, name = sym))}

VIX <- "^VIX"
getSymbols(VIX, src='yahoo', index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"), from='2010-01-01', to = '2015-12-31', env = volEnv) 

vol.close <- do.call(merge, eapply(volEnv, MonthlyAd))
write.table(vol.close, "vol.csv")
```

But what I got is,

```
"","VIX.Adjusted"
"1",12.95
"2",12.34
"3",11.39
"4",11.59
"5",16.440001
```

That would be really helpful if anyone could help me with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't know what the problem is.  `df <- data.frame("3-Month" = rep(NA, 4), row.names = Sys.Date() - 0:3, check.names=FALSE); write.table(df)` works just fine.  `TRUE` is the default value for both `col.names` and `row.names`, so no need to even name those.  For us to help you further, you will need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I agree with what Richard said and will add only that if nothing else you can just write the row names to a column `name$dates <- row.names(name)`

Comment: @N_R I just did a test to see if the date as a row name can make this problem. but not really, here is what I did . df <- structure(list(A = c(3041L, 3079L, 2455L), B = c(114093L, 114730L, 
122074L), C = c(99554L, 99931L, 97737L), D = c(138L, 138L, 145L
)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), row.names = c("2000-05-01", 
"2000-06-01", "2000-07-01"), class = "data.frame") and then write.table(df, file = "names.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE)  which works just fine, so you **must** provide an example data

Comment: Hey thank you all for the helpful comments! I have updated with a replicate and it would be much appreciated if you could have a look. Sorry I did not post it earlier!

Comment: I came back across this post while doing review tasks. I have upvoted and voted to leave open due to his update to the question. N_R -- thanks for the update and even if the code is wrong always include it. That's how we know what you did wrong, so that we can tell you how to fix the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your update to the question, I'd say this is a very good question.

It turns out that your problem was caused by the class of the object you were trying to write to a file, which was `xts`. Apparently the dates in the row names were getting converted to integer when you saved them to a file because of this funny class.

Here's the solution:

```
vol.close <- as.data.frame(vol.close)
write.csv(vol.close, "vol.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Hack-R ! It works perfectly and now I understand I should always ask a question with some background information. Following your instruction I found they mentioned similar thing about xtsAttributes in the xts manual. I don't understand it fully at the moment but I shall study further on this issue. Sorry for the trouble and thanks again!!

Comment: @N_R Happy to help. Best of luck.